# Group by date, with max value and list of comments

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have a following Result table:

```
| id | t_id| value | comment |    date    |
-------------------------------------------
| 1  |  1  |   10  |  test1  | 01-01-2018 |
| 2  |  1  |   20  |  test2  | 01-01-2018 |
| 3  |  1  |   30  |  test3  | 01-01-2018 |
| 4  |  2  |   10  |  NULL   | 01-02-2018 |
| 5  |  2  |   10  |  test5  | 01-03-2018 |
```

and my class for results is:

```
public class ChartResult
{
    public DateTime X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public List<string> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

How to group results by date, return last value and list of comments for each group and map this result in list of ChartResult objects?

Comment: is this using entity framework? i could only propose `context.Result.OrderBy(x => x.Date).GroupBy(x => x.Date).Select(x => new CharResult(){ X = x.First().Date, Y = x.First().Value, Comments = x })` but without actual model it will be a guess. there are some point to be remembered: (1) GroupBy will result in a list of group that each group contains the members (2) projecting the result into new class, use `Select` with `new`. give it a shot, cheers~

Comment: Welcome.  What have you tried?  Good luck

Comment: I had a similar attempt...I have slightly changed your code, and now is okay:
var results = topicResults.OrderBy(x => x.CreatedDate)
                                  .GroupBy(x => x.CreatedDate)
                                  .Select(x => new ChartResult() { X = x.First().CreatedDate, Y = x.First().Value, Comments = x.Where(z => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(z.Comment)).Select(y => y.Comment).ToList() })
                                  .ToList();

Answer (score 0):

I would do it by breaking it as :

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var masterData = new List<Data>
            {
                new Data{ id = 1, t_id =1, value = 10, comment="test1", date=Convert.ToDateTime("01-01-2018") },
                new Data{ id = 2, t_id =1, value = 10, comment="test2", date=Convert.ToDateTime("01-01-2018") },
                new Data{ id = 3, t_id =1, value = 10, comment="test3", date=Convert.ToDateTime("01-01-2018") },
                new Data{ id = 4, t_id =2, value = 10, comment=null, date=Convert.ToDateTime("01-02-2018") },
                new Data{ id = 5, t_id =2, value = 10, comment="test5", date=Convert.ToDateTime("01-03-2018") },
            };

            var chartResults = new List<ChartResult>();

            foreach (var date in masterData.Select(i => i.date).Distinct().ToList())
            {
                var commentsForDate = masterData.Where(i => i.date == date).Select(i => i.comment).ToList();
                var maxValue = masterData.Where(i => i.date == date).Max(i => i.value);
                chartResults.Add(new ChartResult
                {
                    Comments = commentsForDate,
                    X = date,
                    Y = maxValue
                });
            }
        }
    }

    public class ChartResult
    {
        public DateTime X { get; set; }
        public double Y { get; set; }
        public List<string> Comments { get; set; }
    }


    public class Data
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int t_id { get; set; }
        public int value { get; set; }
        public string comment { get; set; }
        public DateTime date { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: How come you didn’t use LINQ’s groupby?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you already have data from SQL in your c# variables. I am just suggesting the manipulation of data into required format

Lets say you data in similar class object myData

```
public class Data
{
   public int id { get; set; }
   public int t_id { get; set; }
   public int value { get; set; }
   public string comment { get; set; }
   public DateTime date { get; set; }
}
```

Data myData;

And you required class is

```
public class ChartResult
{
    public DateTime X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public List<string> Comments { get; set; }
}

myData.GroupBy(x => x.Date).Select(gp => new CharResult(){ X = gp.Key, Y = gp.Max(p => p.value), Comments = gp.Select(p => p.comment).ToList() })
```